# "java.lang.NullPointerException" when saving TextField value - JavaFx

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception, javafx, textfield

I'm trying to save a TextField value into a database but I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException".

What I'd like to happen is to have a client's first name saved into the database when the 'addClient()' method is called.

Could anyone help me get it to work? Thank you all in advance.

The Controller Class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.DB.NewClientDB;

public class NewClientController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public TextField firstName;

    // Initializes the controller class.
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    public void addClient() throws SQLException {
        new NewClientDB().main();
    }
}
```

The database class:

```
import Database.Plain.Skell.DBConnect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.NewClientController;

public class NewClientDB extends NewClientController {

    private String firstNames = new NewClientController().firstName.getText();

    public void main() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DBConnect.connect();
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO KIWI "
                    + "VALUES (102, " + (firstNames) + ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            }// do nothing
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that this is in JavaFx and the 'TextField firstName' is being called from an FXML file that was created using JavaFx SceneBuilder. I've tried initializing it in the controller but no success. Any ideas? I thought these types of objects should not be innitialized, at least going by JavaFx.

The Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.DB.NewClientDB.<init>(NewClientDB.java:12)
    at wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.NewClientController.addClient(NewClientController.java:41)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Can you put your error trace, please?

Comment: Hey [@angel_navarro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2239904/angel-navarro). Thanks for looking at my question. Just added the error trace.

Comment: Seems DBConnect is null...

Comment: I am not a JavaFX developer, but I suspect your `initialize` method needs to have something more than `// TODO` in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No success getting TextField values into database - JavaFx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167519/no-success-getting-textfield-values-into-database-javafx)

Answer (score 2):

In this line, firstName is null

```
private String firstNames = new NewClientController().firstName.getText();
```

you must initilize the variable in a constructor or in at you declare it

public TextField firstName = new TextField();

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is in JavaFx and the 'TextField firstName' is being called from an FXML file that was created using JavaFx SceneBuilder. I've tried initializing it in the controller but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: lastName? In the code that you have posted the variable's name is firstName

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Yes, it's firstName. Like so: private String firstNames = new NewClientController().firstName.getText();

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this line.-

```
private String firstNames = new NewClientController().firstName.getText();
```

is throwing the `NullPointerException`. You're creating a new instance of `NewClientController` but your never initialize `firstName` instance variable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is in JavaFx and the 'TextField firstName' is being called from an FXML file that was created using JavaFx SceneBuilder. I've tried initializing it in the controller but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging step by step and evaluating expression new `NewClientController().firstName` to make sure is not `null`?

Comment: I just started JavaFx. How do I go about that? I'm not sure how to go about that:"debugging step by step and evaluating expression new NewClientController().firstName to make sure is not null".