# No success getting TextField values into database - JavaFx

Tags: java, sql, javafx, textfield

I'm trying to save a TextField value into a database but I get the error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO KIWI VALUES (104, ) [21002-173]
```

What I'd like to happen is to have a client's first name saved into the database when the 'addClient()' method is called.

Could anyone help me get it to work? Thank you all in advance.

I'm working in JavaFx and the 'TextField firstName' is being called from an FXML file that was created using JavaFx SceneBuilder. I've tried initializing it in the controller but no success. Any ideas? I thought these types of objects should not be innitialized, at least going by JavaFx rules as I understand.

The Controller Class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.DB.NewClientDB;

public class NewClientController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public TextField firstName;

    // Initializes the controller class.
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    public void addClient() throws SQLException {
        new NewClientDB().main();
    }
}
```

The database class:

```
import Database.Plain.Skell.DBConnect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.NewClientController;

public class NewClientDB extends NewClientController {

    private String firstNames = new NewClientController().firstName.getText();

    public void main() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DBConnect.connect();
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO KIWI "
                    + "VALUES (104, " + (firstNames) + ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            }// do nothing
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
}
```

**Edit:**
I don't think the TextField values are being picked

Comment: Please don't create many questions that are very similar, instead, if your original question is not answered satisfactorily after a day or two, edit it and update it with the additional things that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote, you should use `PreparedStatements`. You'll avoid concatenation errors as well as SQL injection.

But your problem seems to come from the fact that you're getting the value before the user has had a chance to type anything there. I'm not familiar with JavaFX, but your current code is getting the textfield value at the beginning of the program (when it's obviously still empty). Shouldn't it perform the addition when you click a button or something?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong here.

You cannot create a new controller class with a new statement and expect it to be the same instance as that created by an FXMLLoader.  Delete this line:

```
private String firstNames = new NewClientController().firstName.getText();
```

NewClientDB should not extend NewClientContoller.  The FXMLLoader knows nothing about subclasses.

Pass the firstName from your controller to your NewClientDB instance.

```
new NewClientDB().main(firstName);

....

public void main(String firstNames)
```

Place single quotes around the firstNames string in your insert statement.

```
"INSERT INTO KIWI VALUES (104, '" + (firstNames) + "')";
```

Ensure that your KIWI table only has two columns with types compatible to your insert statement.

Check your FXML supplies an fx:id for firstName.

Check that you have a [button defined in your FXML which triggers #addClient](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers).

If the above doesn't solve your problem, edit your question to include your KIWI table DDL and your FXML file.

Comment: I found some more errors in your program and stuff you can look at and updated my answer for these.  Regarding a PreparedStatement, that is orthogonal to your current issues (i.e. it's potentially a more secure implementation but you should be able to get your code to at least work correctly without it).  I can't comment on specific changes you have made to your code that are not posted in a question edit.